# Embeding Zxing module into Titanium app to read Datamatrix 2d codes on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, titanium, zxing, barcode-scanner

I need to build an hybrid Titanium app with a Datamatrix code scanner.

It seems like the ZXing library has support for Datamatrix codes

I have few experience in integrating such modules and I don't want to waste time trying to achieve something that is not possible.

I also don't wan't to manually implement the solution.

If anyone has experience with both Titanium and ZXing, and hopefully with the Datamatrix barcode standard, I'll take it!

Comment: have you tried ti.barcode module [appcelerator ti.barcode](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/barcode/)

Comment: Not yet. I'd like to know if anyone has and how did it fly for them.

Comment: i have used it in a Checkin application (titanium) . it works very well but i haven't test it in a Datamatrix data type only on barcode & qrcode

Comment: Thanks that's a start. Do you have access to that app or could you share access to it so I could test it on Datamatrix codes?

Comment: From my experience ZXing is very good detecting data-matrixes, as long as they are positioned so the center of the image is inside the data-matrix.